# How to copy folder from host to docker container out of context

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to COPY a folder from host machine to docker container .

I have this structure  :

```
.
├── .docker
│   ├── php
│   │   ├── php7
│   │       ├──Dockerfile
├── php_7   └── 
└── docker-compose.yml
```

docker-compose.yml :

```
  php7:
    build:
      context: .docker/php/php7
```

In the Dockerfile i tried :

```
COPY ../../php_7 /var/www/html
COPY ../../../php_7 /var/www/html
COPY ./php_7 /var/www/html



docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d --build
```

i'm always getting :

> failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: "/php_7" not found: not
> found

How can i correctly copy the folder ?

Comment: What's the executed command and in which directory you are running it?

Comment: I might just move the Dockerfile to the top of the directory tree, next to where you have the `docker-compose.yml` file, and adjust the paths accordingly.  The linked question also describes ways to do it leaving the Dockerfile in a subdirectory.